# Giving inline-block elements with variable content the same height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mootools

I have 4 inline-block elements with fixed width but variable content, and I want all of these elements to have the same height - that of the largest element. Please see [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kKZXj/).

How should I achieve this? If its not possible to do it using only css, what is the right way to do it using javascript?

Comment: would you consider using jquery?

Comment: Its not really possible as the project already uses Mootools, which is a similarly sized library. There would likely be problems with running both. I'm interested in any JQuery-based solutions though, incase there is a mootools equivilent.

Comment: Do you need IE7 support?

Comment: If possible I'd like IE7 support, but I'm mainly going for IE8. If there is a solution that doesn't work for IE7, but does degrade gracefully for that browser, I am interested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

probably better to make it modular and reusable, in mootools, you can prototype a HTML collection:

```
Elements.implement({
    setEqualHeight: function(height) {
        height = height || Math.max.apply(Math, this.map(function(el) { 
            return el.getSize().y 
        }));
        this.setStyle("height", height);
    }
});

// use tallest as height for all
document.getElements("div.equals").setEqualHeight(); 
// or hardwire all to 500...
document.getElements("div.equals").setEqualHeight(500);
```

fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/TxtBQ/2/

and with your ul/li: http://jsfiddle.net/kKZXj/8/

works on anything, they don't even need to be close to each other

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a `height` and `overflow` style to the `<li>` elements

```
height: 200px;
overflow: auto;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kKZXj/1/

---

may not be exactly what you're looking for with using the largest element as the height.

Another way to do this would be use a `<table>` element and each cell would give you the desired effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/kKZXj/3/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but having a scrollbar won't work for what I need here. I'm tempted to use tables for layout, but if my friends see it they'll barrage me with links to this page: `http://shouldiusetablesforlayout.com/`.

Comment: @Oliver You can use CSS tables, which will create the same effect without the semantic issues table elements introduce.

For example: <div style="display:table;"><span style="display:table-cell;"></span></div>

Answer (score 2):

[Ta-dahhhh](http://jsfiddle.net/kKZXj/6/)!

Although it requires an Object.each() loop. Sort of hacky, but works for your purposes.

Relevent javascript:

```
// Calculate the target height of all of the li elements
var targetHeight = document.getElement('ul').getStyle('height');

// Then set their heights to the calculated max
document.getElements('li').each(function(element, key) {
    element.setStyle('height', targetHeight);
});
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. I think I'll do something like that. It will fit in pretty well for me in this case, as I have a function called `renderSearchHistory()` (where these elements are made). For general cases though, i'm a bit worried that putting lots of layout js in will make my site confusing to maintain

Comment: I realized after looking at the code that iterating through all of the `li` elements (like the other answers) isn't necessary, since the `ul` expands to the target height anyway.

Comment: The only issue i have with this is if you apply `padding` to the `ul` element. In that case you're actually increasing all the `li` element's height by the amount of the padding + the max `li`, instead of just the max `li`'s height.

Comment: That's a legitimate concern. If that were the case, perhaps innerHeight may work, although cross-browser compatibility is another issue there.

Comment: this is not scalable, you measure height of the parent element - it should be relevant to the tallest element there is, regardless of parent, parent padding or elements' position or display properties. also, this is not an `OBJECT.EACH` loop. it is a `htmlcollection.each` (think, a prototyped array of elements).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pure javascript solution:

```
var height = 0,
    lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li'),
    i;

for (i=0; lis[i]; i++) {
    height = Math.max( height, lis[i].offsetHeight );
}

for (i=0; lis[i]; i++) {
    lis[i].style.height = height+'px';
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kKZXj/7/

And here is a jQuery way: http://jsfiddle.net/kKZXj/5/

You can also fake it, by adding borders and background images to the parent elements that simulates the same visual effect, even if the elements are of different height.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an elegant jQuery way :)

http://jsfiddle.net/rifat/yG2xt/

Comment: Very nice! But doesn’t this loop all matched elements for each element?

Comment: Just that while it looks nice, it might not be very efficient under the hood. That’s all.

Answer (score 1):

Give your ul an id of `myUl` and try running the following script. It works on motools. First fetch the max height of the li elements and then set each one's height with the value.

```
 var ul = document.getElementById("myUL"); // get the UL 
 var liNodes = ul.getElementsByTagName("li"); // Iterate through the li's
 var maxHeight = -1; 
 for( var i = 0; i < liNodes.length; i++ ) {
    // get the child nodes of the li  
   var li = liNodes.item(i);  
   if(maxHeight < li.offsetHeight)
         maxHeight = li.offsetHeight; 
 }

 for( var i = 0; i < liNodes.length; i++ ) { // get the child nodes of the li 
   liNodes.item(i).style.height = maxHeight+'px'; //set heights 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple jQuery plugin which also automatically resizes elements when window size is changed.

Change **.my-inline-block-class** to a jQuery selector that will select your inline-block elements.

```
(function($, window) {
    var $ls, $t;
    function autoheight() {
        var max = 0;
        $ls.each(function() {
            $t = $(this);
            $t.css('height','');
            max = Math.max(max, $t.height());
        });
        $ls.height(max);
    }
    $(function() {
        $ls = $('.my-inline-block-class'); // the inline-block selector
        autoheight(); // first time
        $ls.on('load', autoheight); // when images in content finish loading
        $(window).resize(autoheight); // when the window size changes
    });
})(jQuery, window);
```