# mootools 1.12 to 1.25 update script difficulties

Tags: javascript, mootools

hi i have a mootools script that works in version 1.12 but i want to update to 1.25 and it throws an error. 
here is the script:

```
 window.addEvent('load', function() {


 Array.extend({  
    equalize: function(){
        maxHeight = [];

        this.each(function(el){
            maxHeight.push(el.getSize().size.y);
        });
        this.setStyle('height', Math['max'].apply(Math, maxHeight));
    }
});
$$('#col1,#col2,#col3,#col4,#col5').equalize();
$$('.column,.general').equalize();
  });
```

pretty simple but i dont know what i need to do to update it for the newer version of mootools. the error in ie9 is the following:

Error Message: Object doesn't support property or method 'equalize'

Comment: firebug gives a little more info: $$("#col1,#col2,#col3,#col4,#col5").equalize is not a function

Comment: i have now tried changing the $$ to $ and taking off the # symbol. no luck and wrapping in a protected function document.id... no luck

Comment: this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677956/giving-inline-block-elements-with-variable-content-the-same-height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MooTools 1.2+ there's no `size` object of the `getSize()` method, so: `el.getSize().size.y` becomes `el.getSize().y`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wagEJ/

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `implement` instead of `extend`. Extend only adds a static method whereas implement alters the prototype of the Class.

That being said, you would probably want to use `Elements` instead of `Array` as `equalize` makes no sense for an untyped array (Elements can be considered an array that is only filled with Element items)

tl;dr: your code should read `Elements.implement` instead of `Array.extend`